# How to hide object property to display using angular ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to hide `_id` to display on UI using `ng-model` , I see alot of examples of filtering data using ng-repeat but i did not find angular solution to achieve this task using ng-model.How can hide `_id` property to display ?

main.html

```
<div ng-jsoneditor="onLoad" ng-model="obj.data" options="obj.options" ></div>
```

Ctrl.js

```
$scope.obj.data = {
    "_id": "58a3322bac70c63254ba2a9c",
    "name": "MailClass",
    "id": "MailTask_1",
    "createdBy": "tyuru",
    "__v": 0,
    "properties": [{
        "label": "Java Package Name",
        "type": "String",
        "editable": true,
        "binding": {
            "type": "property",
            "name": "camunda:class"
        },
        "$$hashKey": "object:29"
    }],
    "appliesTo": [
        "bpmn:ServiceTask"
    ]
}

var json = {};

function loadCurrentUserAndTemplate() {
    AuthService.getCurrentUser()
        .then(function(resp) {
            $scope.currentUser = resp.data.id;
            // console.log($scope.currentUser);
            userTemplate($scope.currentUser);
        });
}

loadCurrentUserAndTemplate();

$scope.obj = {
    data: json,
    options: {
        mode: 'tree'
    }
};

var privateFields = removePrivateFields($scope.obj.data, ['_id', '__v']);

// add private fields back to $scope.obj.data before POST
var modifiedData = Object.assign({}, $scope.obj.data, privateFields);


function removePrivateFields(obj, props) {
    var output = {};
    props.forEach(function(prop) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            output[prop] = obj[prop];
            delete obj[prop];
        }
    });
    return output;
}

function userTemplate(user) {
    // console.log('inside template',$scope.currentUser);
    templateService.getUserTemplates(user)
        .then(function(response) {
                // console.log('userTemplate',response.data);
                // console.log(response.data.length);
                $scope.displayedTemplates = response.data;
                if (response.data.length !== 0 && response.data !== null) {
                    $scope.obj.data = response.data[0];

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a function like `removePrivateFields` to strip the private fields from original object and attach them back to the modified object before submitting to server

```js
// for testing
var $scope = { obj: {} };

var jsonData = {
  "_id": "58a3322bac70c63254ba2a9c",
  "name": "MailClass",
  "id": "MailTask_1",
  "createdBy": "tyuru",
  "__v": 0,
  "properties": [{
    "label": "Java Package Name",
    "type": "String",
    "editable": true,
    "binding": {
      "type": "property",
      "name": "camunda:class"
    },
    "$$hashKey": "object:29"
  }],
  "appliesTo": [
    "bpmn:ServiceTask"
  ]
};

var privateFields = removePrivateFields(jsonData, ['_id', '__v']);

// private fields got removed form actual jsonData
$scope.obj.data = jsonData;
console.log($scope.obj.data);

// once edit
// add private fields back to $scope.obj.data before POST
var modifiedData = Object.assign({}, $scope.obj.data, privateFields);
console.log(modifiedData);

function removePrivateFields(obj, props) {
  var output = {};
  props.forEach(function(prop) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      output[prop] = obj[prop];
      delete obj[prop];
    }
  });
  return output;
}
```

Comment: When i will update object i will need `_id` so i am just clarifying we just want to hide them not completly remove. will it work for update ?

Comment: sorry i did not see the bottom part got it.

Comment: I updated my question its only working for first index of `$scope.obj.data`. we are loading data dynamically i understand we assigned value `response.data[0]` but if we just assign response data it does not work and shows all the properties.

Comment: you need to run this `$scope.privateFields = removePrivateFields($scope.obj.data, ['_id', '__v']);` every time before assigning the `$scope.obj.data = response.data[0];`

Answer (score 0):

It would be both more performant and along Angular best practices to instead delegate this functionality into your controller or the service fetching the object.

Ideally, you want to perform any object manipulation or formatting within an Angular service, but you could also do it within your controller (probably fine if you're just instantiating your JSON editor with mock data).

Comment: Understood , Any angular method to hide object property ?